# How do i use one string array entry based upon its position within the array (Android)?

Tags: android, string, android-arrayadapter, arrays

I'm trying to produce a simple oracle app where when you ask the app a question it spits out an answer based on a random number.

I've done some research and it seems to me the best practice way of doing things is to create a resource for my answers containing a string array, i can then type my various answers in to the array.

In my Java code in my main activity i can then generate a random number upon the click of a button. This random number can then correspond to the number of the index.

My problem comes when i try to piece the random number and the facility to access the string array together in code.

Here is a copy of my answerStrings.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
    <string-array
    name="answers">
    <item>Yes</item>
    <item>No</item>
    <item>Maybe</item>
    <item>Quite possibly</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Here is my java code:

```
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

TextView    outputText;
MediaPlayer mpGobble;
Vibrator    vibr;
String[]    answers;
private Random myRandom = new Random();
int         randomNumber;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //find the output text view for use within the activity

    outputText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView01);

    outputText.setOnClickListener(this);

    //Declare an array of outputs
    Resources res = getResources();
    String[] answers = res.getStringArray(R.array.answers);
    //--------^ Problem

    outputText.setText("Ask your question then click me");
}


@Override
public void onClick(View src) {
    switch(src.getId()){
    case R.id.textView01:

        //creates a random number
        int randomNumber = myRandom.nextInt(3);

        String answer = answers[randomNumber];

        outputText.setText(answer);




            break;
    }

}
}
```

I'm programming in Java with the eclipse IDE and as you have probably guessed i'm new to the game!

All help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The below code will put your String resource array into a String[] called answers.

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] answers = res.getStringArray(R.array.answers);
```

You can then select your answer with

```
String answer = answers[YOUR_RANDOM_WHOLE_NUMBER];
```

An FYI, string arrays in resources can only be 512 entries long.
[Some string resource help](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)
[Some general resource class help](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html)

Comment: Wow that was a quick reply! now about to try it and will send some feedback.

Comment: I get a warning local variable is never read on answers from the first chunk of code and also on answer in the second chunk of code.

Comment: If the second chunk compiles, then it's definitely reading from the answers, and answers would not be unused. To make answer used, you will probably want to display it somehow, maybe by oding setText on a TextView?

Comment: I cleared the problem with the second chunk of code, it was just me being a dummy! I forgot to print the string result to the TextView.
However i still have problem with the first answers, local variable is never read.

Comment: Ah-Ha! fixed it, i've casted answers to a type twice so the compiler didnt like it, the solution was to remove the String[] from the first chunk of code!!

Thanks for your help Mike dg!!